# How to correctly set the value of a "point" field into a MySql database table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms, opengis

I am pretty new in database and I working on a MySql database.

Into a table I have a field named **geographical_position** having **POINT** as data type. This field represent the GPS position of a point on a map.

I tryied to insert a value as **41.729086, 12.278478** for a record of this table form my IDE but it was not initialized (it appear **null**)

Now trying to update it by the IDE (setting it "as text) butI obtain the following error message:

```
#22003Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field
```

What is the correct way to insert the coordinates of this point into this **POINT** field?

Comment: You can read this documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/populating-spatial-columns.html
there are also examples

Answer (score 1):

Check the **[manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/populating-spatial-columns.html)**:

```
 INSERT INTO geom VALUES (ST_GeomFromText('POINT(41.729086 12.278478)'));
```